# Como parsear Json con retrofit

Tags: android-studio, retrofit

Webservice response

```
{
    "estado": 400,
    "mensaje": "Usuario o Password invalidos"
}
```

Estoy empezando hacer uso de retrofit, hay unas partes que no entiendo cabe decir que es la primera ves que lo utilizo.

Cree mi modelo en base a esos dos parametros de respuesta que tengo en este caso 
 solo necesitare mensaje

```
@SerializedName("mensaje")
private String mensaje;
@SerializedName("username")
private String username;
@SerializedName("email")
private String email;
@SerializedName("password")
private String password;

CONSTRUCT (email, password) ...
GET AND SET ...
```

Usando retrofit.

```
Call<LoginModel> call = MainActivity.apiInterface.loginUser(loginModel);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){


                } else{
                    // errores 400...etc
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Como debería ser utilizado, es decir como obtengo "mensaje" de mi api y mostrarlo por consola para no hacerlo largo.
Puedo hacer la petición correctamente, pero no se como parsear los datos intente usar lo siguiente en mi respuesta, pero me tira error. ¿Que me falta?

```
String message = response.body().getMensaje();
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes parsear tu pojo desde este sitio, te genera la clase java dependeindo de tu JSON
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
[image: Un ejemplo de como estructurarlo en la pagina]

una vez lo hagas puedes intentar con el metodo de parseo Gson, en tu Builder de retrofit lo haces de esta manera:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder ()
                    .baseUrl (urlServidorRest)
                    .addConverterFactory (GsonConverterFactory.create ())
                    .build ();
```

Saludos